# Firebase onMessageReceived() returns no getNotification

Tags: java, android, firebase, wonderpush

Calling `remoteMessage.getNotification()` returns `null` and
when calling `remoteMessage.getData()` I get a strange object back that has an initial property `_wp={` as listed below. I need to extract the alert property each time but I am not sure how.

```java
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    
    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

    Log.d("DATA", remoteMessage.getData().toString());
    sendNotification(data);
}
```

The remote data log returns the below. So I can't seem get the title and text I need to in order to construct my notification.

```
{_wp={"c":"01euntvtna3epk83","alert":{"text":"Body text","title":"test"},"receipt":false,"type":"simple","targetUrl":"wonderpush:\/\/notificationOpen\/default","n":"01eunu08bjla8303","reporting":{"campaignId":"01euntvtna3epk83","notificationId":"01eunu08bjla8303"},"receiptUsingMeasurements":true}, alert=Body text}
```

I basically want to use them with when using the `NotificationCompat.Builder`

```java
.setContentTitle(title)
.setContentText(text)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal that `remoteMessage.getNotification()` returns `null` as WonderPush only uses FCM notifications with data inside them, nothing in the Firebase's own format.

`remoteMessage.getData()` returns you with a map that can only store String values. This corresponds to the top-level JSON payload. This map's fields are the top-level JSON object fields, and its values are all stringified.
So you'll have to parse the `_wp` key using `new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().get("_wp"))`.
You'll basically read the `title` and `text` fields of this parsed `_wp` JSON object to feed `.setContentTitle()` and `.setContentText()` of the `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

But you should note that the WonderPush Android SDK is precisely here for that purpose:

- Here is the code that parses the notification's `_wp.alert` field: https://github.com/wonderpush/wonderpush-android-sdk/blob/v4.0.2/sdk/src/main/java/com/wonderpush/sdk/AlertModel.java
- Here is the code that builds the notification: https://github.com/wonderpush/wonderpush-android-sdk/blob/v4.0.2/sdk/src/main/java/com/wonderpush/sdk/NotificationManager.java#L448-L775

If you have an addition, it would make more sense to fork, hack, submit a pull request, and use your fork in the meanwhile.

Best,

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @ofavre I will check try your suggestion and get back to you.